# Is there a more intuitive way to use Inline Assembly in C++ in Linux than the GCC or Clang implementation?

Tags: c++, linux, inline-assembly

My preferred OS is Ubuntu and my preferred IDE is Code::Blocks.

I have some decent experience with C++, and today I just started learning Assembly, and am using C++ inline assembly in my IDE for convenience.

The syntax for GCC/Clang inline assembly is bizarre and it would seem to be a terrible idea to use it while learning assembly.

For now, I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 10 inside VirtualBox, which has an `_asm` macro that allows the use of native assembly syntax, and I would simply like to know if there is a way to achieve the same experience on Linux.

Comment: Yes, inline assembly is bizarre and not to be used when learning assembly. Instead, write a proper assembly code in it's own `.s` file and compile it with `gas`.

Comment: @SergeyA is correct in my opinion here. You also should know that there is no inline asm support for 64bit visual c++ projects. You can, however, make asm files that get compiled through the visual c++ compiler pipeline and that works for both x86 and x64. Regarding Linux, your best bet is to use a compiler that can compile assembly raw without inlining it in c++ code. Inline assembly usually causes more issues than it is worth. Some compilers may try to optimize your inline assembly and depending on how the parent scope is optomized, you may experience some very strange issues.

Comment: @MaxKunes : Curious if you know of a particular C/C++ compiler that optimizes the actual inline assembly. GCC/CLANG/ICC don't and I don't believe MSVC does either but there may be one out there that does. Just curious if you might know which.

Comment: Intel's ICC compiler which is available on Linux (as well as Windows) supports both GCC/CLang's inline assembly syntax and MSVC. Codeblocks I believe has logic in its setup to support using the Intel ICC compiler. ICC supports GCC/Clang and MSVC inline assembly in both 32-bit and 64-bit code (unlike Microsoft's compiler)

Comment: Clang supports `-fasm-blocks` for MSVC-style inline asm, but it's not 100% compatible.  (e.g. leaving a value in EAX and then falling off the end of a non-void function is not supported in clang as a way to return a value when optimizing, and maybe not even in debug mode.  But it is in MSVC.  See comments on [How to get locations of asm statements with clang frontend](//stackoverflow.com/q/50713476))

Answer (score 3):

You can use *intrinsic functions* instead of inline assembly. An intrinsic function is analogous to an assembly instruction, but much easier to use because you don't have to worry about registers and calling conventions. There are intrinsic functions for almost all assembly instructions that don't have a C++ equivalent.
See https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide